# iPhone Core Data Fetch Primary Key

Tags: iphone, core-data, primary-key

I am developing an application that uses CoreData.

So in **.sqlite** file, It manages Primary key itself.

Primary key attribute name is **Z_PK**.

My problem is that, I wants data from my table sorted ascending by primary key.

I'm using that code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_PK" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[sort release];
```

But it's not working.

when I'm using "title" insted of "_PK", It's working Fine

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[sort release];
```

So is there any different way to use Table's Primary key?

Comment: Could you post an image or your Xcdatanodel,because your question is a bit not clear?

Comment: **Primary key in Core Data?**

Comment: Hello Nikita, I m Writing .Sqlite file into Document Directory.

Comment: In that file When i m adding some record, then table create primary key for all records..I just need to use this Primary Key for Sorting My data.

Comment: Oops. I think you can't play with that SQLite file in documents directory. Its for internal use by Core Data. Have you referred Core Data Documentation properly?

Comment: yes anonymous...primary key for records into the .Sqlite file.

Comment: yes it's for internal use by core data..But I can Change it's Data So I think I might be able to use it's Primary key.

Comment: Don't do that. Core Data is Core Data. Not a database

Comment: Ok..It means It's not possible ? or should I not use That?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoreData manages persistent object graphs.  It is not a RDBM.  You have no control over the unique primary key, so you have no control over its value.  It is merely an implementation detail, and should not be referenced for any reason.

Thus, why do you want to sort based on it?  I can think of several reasons...

1. You want to access the objects in the order in which they were added to the database.  However, you can easily do this in several ways.

1a. You can add a field to each Entity.  You can set it to be a UUID, or in increasing integer.

1b. You could have an entity, something like "EntityList" which has an ordered one-to-many relationship to "Entity."

1c. You could add a one-to-one relationship from Entity to itself, then just manage it like a linked list.  Every time you add an Entity, put it at the end of the list.

Either of this solutions give you the ability to access the Entity objects in order they were added.

1. Or, you really don't care the order you see them, but you want a consistent ordering.

2a. Add a primaryKey attribute, and assign it a UUID.

2b. Use the ordered to-many relationship.

Finally, if you really want primary-key-based access, I would suggest having a separate sqlite database that you use for special keyed access.  You can then associate a key to the objectID of an object in the CoreData store.

Comment: Thank you Jody, i have a alter net solution for that. But I just wanted to know that it's possible or not ? Thanks for help.