# iOS Get objects from CoreData sorted by primary key

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have saved data into db using CoreData. I need to fetch data from my table in same order that it was saved. Inside table it is ordered by Z_PK - hidded CoreData key. How can I create such sort descriptor. If I use fetch request without sort descriptors my data objects have wrong order.

Comment: Why dont you want to use a sort descriptor with your fetch request?

Comment: It is sensitive data. Any sort descriptor changes order :(

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153335/iphone-core-data-fetch-primary-key

Comment: Is this static data in a sqlite database? Or are you asking how you can achieve this for data you are planning to save?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything not exposed to you by the Core Data framework is an implementation detail. The fact that `Z_PK` exists, and currently suits your purposes, cannot be relied upon.

If creation/save order is important to your model, then it should be included in your model. There's really nothing else to it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no proper method in core data framework to sort object by primary key, but I think we can use objectID as a the primary key and sort by objectID. ObjectID for a particular object would always increase.. thus you can use below method

```
/*!
@param <NSManagedObject> array 
@return <NSManagedObject> sortedarray
*/

+ (NSArray *) sortManagedObjectArrayByObjectID:(NSArray *) array {

    NSArray *compareResult = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSManagedObject *obj1, NSManagedObject *obj2) {

        NSString *s = [obj1.objectID.URIRepresentation lastPathComponent];
        NSString *r = [obj2.objectID.URIRepresentation lastPathComponent];
        return [s compare:r];

    }];

    return compareResult;

}
```

Hope this would help

Comment: This seems to sort the objectID's as string, which doesn't give the correct result

Answer (score 1):

Use a sort descriptor with `self` as the sort key. The underlying SQL will have `ORDER BY t0.Z_PK`.